# Display ViewBag content in a dialog box view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I am trying to show an alert message on submitting a request. The alert message should be the content of ViewBag. Here is my view.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Request";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.message))
{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var msg = "@ViewBag.message";
        alert(msg);
    </script>
}
```

There is no alert even when ViewBag.message has value in it.

Comment: have you tried wrapping it `document.ready` ?

Comment: can you provide action from which you are returning this view?

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.message = TempData["Message"].ToStr();
            return View();
         }

Comment: are you sure `TempData["Message"]` is returning something because your script looks fine and can you use  `var check = TempData["message"].ToString();`  and place a break point to check the value

Comment: @Usman Yes, the ViewBag.message has data in it. I have added the breakpoint and checked. It goes inside the if condition but the thing is that it doesn't execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var msg = "@ViewBag.message";
        alert(msg);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I put the alert inside document ready function and it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Just tested it and it does work for me. Do you have any other javascript functions after this one?

Comment: No there aren't any functions there is only a div tag.